# Spring Boot Admin can't differ between multiple service instances in Cloudfoundry

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I got Spring Boot Admin running locally with Eureka Service Discovery (No SBA Dependeny in the Clients). Now i tried to deploy it in Cloudfoundry. According the Documentation, Version 2.0.1 should "support CloudFoundry out of the box".

My Problem is that when I scale a service up to multiple instances, they are all registered under the same hostname and port. Eureka shows me all Instances with their InstanceID that I configured like this:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
```

But Spring Boot Admin only lists one instance with hostname:port as identifier. I think i have to configure something on the client so that it sends the instance ID per HTTP Header when registering. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to set the ApplicationId and InstanceIndex that Cloudfoundry generates as Eureka ApplicationId and InstanceId at Startup/ContextRefresh of your Client.

CloudFoundryApplicationInitializer.kt

```
@Component
@Profile("cloud")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CloudFoundryApplicationProperties::class)
class CloudFoundryApplicationInitializer {

private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudFoundryApplicationInitializer::class.java)

@Autowired
private val applicationInfoManager: ApplicationInfoManager? = null

@Autowired
private val cloudFoundryApplicationProperties: CloudFoundryApplicationProperties? = null

@EventListener
fun onRefreshScopeRefreshed(event: RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent) {
    injectCfMetadata()
}

@PostConstruct
fun onPostConstruct() {
    injectCfMetadata()
}

fun injectCfMetadata() {

    if(this.cloudFoundryApplicationProperties == null) {
        log.error("Cloudfoundry Properties not set")
        return
    }

    if(this.applicationInfoManager == null) {
        log.error("ApplicationInfoManager is null")
        return
    }

    val map = applicationInfoManager.info.metadata
    map.put("applicationId", this.cloudFoundryApplicationProperties.applicationId)
    map.put("instanceId", this.cloudFoundryApplicationProperties.instanceIndex)

    }
}
```

CloudFoundryApplicationProperties.kt

```
@ConfigurationProperties("vcap.application")
class CloudFoundryApplicationProperties {
    var applicationId: String? = null
    var instanceIndex: String? = null
    var uris: List<String> = ArrayList()
}
```